# How do I use other API versions as build targets in my Android Project?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-sdk-manager

## Introduction

1. I'm new to Android Development
2. Using **Eclipse Luna r24.1.2** and **JDK 8**
3. I can't use Android Studio because it **lags too much** on my computer

## The Problem

I can't choose a build target in the `Compile With` dropdown that is above API version 8. However, I can choose a minimum and target API's that are greater than this.

Hence, **I cannot start a project / choose an activity.**

**How do I overcome this? Do I need to download anything through SDK manager?**

[image: Eclipse Window]

Comment: suggestion  : switch to android-studio. This is not related to your question

Comment: Yes, but my system is old and i don't know for what reason, android studio lags a lot .. even while just typing. not facing that with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Download the API versions

You need to **download the API versions** you wish to use via the [SDK manager](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html). Once you have done this, all of the downloaded versions will appear as options in the `Compile With` drop down.

## Installing via the SDK Manager (Eclipse)

1. Window > Android SDK Manager
2. Check additional API versions required *e.g. Android 4.0 (API14)*
3. Press install [x] packages
4. Restart Eclipse

[image: SDK Manager]

> These instructions are from the [SDK Manager guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html). This also details instructions for **Android Studio** and other operating systems (**Mac**, **Linux**).

---

*I would personally recommend moving to use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html), but that choice is up to you.*

Comment: how do i download ? which package specifically? could you please suggest download of any one package that would help solve this problem? bcoz ive downloaded all the min. pkgs as described on the android official site

Comment: Should i just download the SDK platform of the Latest Version ?(5.1.1)

Comment: Ok, done with download of 5.1.1 (API Level 22)  Package. It works!! Thank You :)